# Как отобразить и записать в коде элементы меню в обратном порядке с помощью js?

Tags: javascript

```
<header>
  <nav>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">link_1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">link_2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">link_3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">link_4</a></li>
          <li><a href="">link_5</a></li>          
</ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: найти все элементы в массив, а потом пройтись по этому массиву в обратном порядке, и записать элементы.

Comment: Тут не хватает собственной попытки решить задачу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть JQuery, то:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#reverse").click(function() {
    var list = $('#someli');
    var listItems = list.children('li');
    list.append(listItems.get().reverse());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul id="someli">
      <li><a href="">link_1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">link_2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">link_3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">link_4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">link_5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<a id="reverse" href="#">Reverse!</a>
```

<sub>[честно украдено с enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347839/jquery-reversing-the-order-of-child-elements)</sub>

Comment: Спасибо огромное, но возможно ли это без использования дополнительной кнопки Reverse? а скажем просто с использованием чистого jquery методом reverse()

Comment: @martynuk возможно - просто вынесите код (3 строчки) из обработчика кнопки и поставьте его куда вам нужно. Кнопка тут просто для того, чтобы было на что нажать в примере. Если бы код стоял прямо в $(function(){ ... }) - то меню сразу бы разворачивалось при загрузке, и эффекта не было бы видно.

Comment: Еще раз благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Если что - вот вариант без jQuery.

```
<header>
<nav>
    <ul id="list">
        <li><a href="">link_1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link_2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link_3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link_4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link_5</a></li>          
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```
var list = document.getElementById('list'),
    elements = list.querySelectorAll('li');

list.innerHTML= Array.prototype.slice.call(elements)
    .reverse()
    .map(function(el){
        return el.outerHTML;
    }).join('');
```